# choosing even-numbered rows from a file

Tags: bash, scripting

How do I choose even numbered rows of a file?
I wish to select rows #2, 4, 6, etc. from a file that contains data. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you should provide sample data next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An awk example (as an alternative to [Mark's sed example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792266/choosing-rows-form-a-file/1792301#1792301)):

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 0' filename
```

Example:

```
$ cat filename
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8

$ awk 'NR % 2 == 0' filename
line 1
line 3
line 5
line 7
```

Comment: `awk '(NR + 1) % 2 ' filename`

Comment: It also depends on how you're considering your line indices (whether or not you want the first line to be 0 or 1).

Comment: The OP said "#2", etc., so that would mean starting on the second (one-indexed) or **third** (zero-indexed) line. Both your updated `NR % 2 == 0` version and my comment `(NR + 1) % 2` start on the second (one-indexed) line.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -n 'n;p' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{getline;print}' filename
```

With `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    read line
    echo $line
done < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `sed` is GNU's:

```
sed -n 2~2p filename
```